# Refelection , Collections, Dictonaries Oh My!

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, collections

I am having a bit of a problem using reflection and accessing collections:

```
XmlElement xmlObject = Scene.CreateElement("Object");
Type Target = obj.GetType();

... xml code here

PropertyInfo[] props = Target.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Static);

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
 Type propType = prop.PropertyType;

 if ((propType.IsPublic && propType.IsValueType && prop.CanRead && prop.CanWrite)
  || PropertyNameExceptions.Contains(prop.Name)
  || PropertyTypeExceptions.Contains(prop.PropertyType.Name))
 {

  object result = null;
  try
  {
   result = prop.GetValue(obj, null);
  }
  catch
  {

  }
  }

 else if (isCollection(result))
 {

  Type pType = result.GetType();
  PropertyInfo[] pTypeInfo = pType.GetProperties();

  ICollection<object> rCollection = null;
  try
  {
   rCollection = (ICollection<object>)prop.GetValue(obj, null);
  }
  catch
  {

  }

  foreach (object o in rCollection)
  {
   ObjectToXML(o, xmlPropertyObject);
  }
 }   
}

private bool isCollection(object o)
{
 if (o.GetType().GetInterface("ICollection") != null)
 {
 return true;
 }

 return false;
}
```

Unable to cast object of type 'ValueCollection[System.String,Axiom.Core.MovableObject]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[System.Object]'.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What are you trying to achieve, what does your code do and where exactly do you get the error message? People will gladly help you here, but please don't just dump the code and the error message and expect someone to debug it for you...

Comment: Insted of "o.GetType().GetInterface("ICollection") != null" you can use "o is ICollection" or "o as ICollection".  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28VS.71%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You test if the non generic version of `ICollection` is implementend by an object and hapilly try to cast it to `ICollection<Object>` ...

Either test if the object really implement `ICollection<Object>` :

```
private bool isCollection(object o)
{
    return o is ICollection<object>;
}
```

or use something like

```
rCollection = ((IEnumerable)prop.GetValue(obj, null)).OfType<Object>().ToList();
```